# .Net HttpClient.timeout means what?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am working on HttpClient.timeout in .NET Core 2.2. I am wondering that - the timeout here counts the connection time (time when the request builds the connection with the remote host) and the socket time (after connection builds, the time for the host to wait for incoming data) as a whole or just connection time?

I've searched [the official docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netframework-4.8) but there seems no explanation. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

with [WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/)  You can set different timeouts as you can see bellow

```
        var httpMessageHandler = new System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler();
        httpMessageHandler.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(150);
        httpMessageHandler.ReceiveDataTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80);
        httpMessageHandler.ReceiveHeadersTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(70);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
```

for you question as far as i know httpClient.Timeout is the whole but you can test it with the above.

Comment: why http client handler ?
it doesnt support HTTP/2.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23134